# How to convert BSTR string to Unsigned Char (Using com technology in the appln)

Tags: visual-c++, com

I am writing small application which uses com technology. I want to convert BSTR string to an unsigned char.  To do this, i used W2A() Macro to convert from BSTR to String and then copied String.C_STR() to an unsigned char array. The code snippet is as follows:

```
Send(BSTR *packet, int length)
{ 
     std::string strPacket = W2A(*packet);
     unsigned char * pBuffer = new unsigned char [strPacket.length()+1];
     memset(pBuffer,0,strPacket.length()+1); 
     memcpy(pBuffer,strPacket.c_str(),strPacket.length()+1);
}
```

This works fine when *packet* contains normal string. But if the *packet* contains a NUL character in it, the problem occurs. Some unknown characters appear after that NUL in the *pBuffer* i.e, after conversion.

Can anyone please let me know how to avoid that? Or is there any other way to do it correctly?

Comment: W2A expects a null-terminated string so it will ignore everything beyond that null character so you should never get any unknown characters.

Comment: @sharptooth Thanks for that. Is there any other way or function which retains everything even after the null character which i can use instead of W2A. I want the conversion to happen correctly even when the NUL is present in the string.

Comment: Unlike a C string, a BSTR can contain embedded zeros.  That made it often abused to store an array of bytes instead of a string.  Which already has an appropriate COM Automation type, a SAFEARRAY.  But if it is actually an array of bytes then converting from Unicode to ANSI stops making sense.  And will fail badly if it contains a single byte that's 0 since that looks like a Chinese character to the conversion routine.  Building awareness in your code of exactly how the buffer is structured and which parts *actually* store a string is required.

Answer (score 0):

A BSTR is a Windows API type and must be managed with API macros or functions. If you cannot use W2A macro because your string may have null chars inside, you will have to use functions as WideCharToMultiByte that can convert from wide characters of BSTR to narrow chararacters for a char*. Be sure to have the SDK documentation. Alternatively, you could make you program use WCHARs